# Adding keywords to a question to help improve future search?

Tags: discussion, edits, seo

I have been searching for a solution here a while and by chance, not by search, I found a question that answered what I was looking for.

Later I realised that I could help others find this question/answer by maybe adding my initial keywords/search-query in a comment, because the question was a good one but it was formulated without the specific keywords.

Whats the best way to go about? 
Can I write a comment with the most probable search query?

Comment: That more sounds like the question needs an edit to introduce the better wording. If you make that edit your self make sure to also give a very clear and extensive edit comment so the reviewers get why you add all kind of new terms to the post. make sure to not alter the intent of the question nor to change code.

Comment: @rene should I suggest to the author of the question to edit and add mote meta information to the question?

Comment: That can also work it is the highest chance on success.

Comment: Question SEO is very tricky.  There are a lot of top-hits that point to a very brief unresearched question with an extensive answer that has been around for years.  So pretty much the exact opposite of what many meta users consider proper Q+A :)  I'd assume that the keywords in the answers matter too, maybe how often googlers click on the URL.  Fairly sure that a good title is very important.

Answer (score -1):

I think a reasonable way to do this would be to add a comment to the question like:

> I searched for "whatever" but didn't find this question in my initial results.